# Change coordinate of map (MapKit)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

**I want change the location of my map** with personnal coordonate.
(when I say "personnal", is not the "user location" but just random coordonate).

This is my MapView Controller :

```
class MapSubViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

  let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.mapLocationUpdate(70.0, longitude: 70.0, title: "")
  }

  func mapLocationUpdate(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, title: String) {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    self.centerMapOnLocation(location, title: title)
  }

  func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String) {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    self.mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: false)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = title
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
  }

}
```

I tell my function "mapLocationUpdate" when i want change the location of my map :

Here for example :

```
  func addMapView(xPosition: Double, yPosition: Double, title: String) {
    self.mapSubViewController = (self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapSubViewController") as? MapSubViewController)!
    self.mapSubViewController.mapLocationUpdate(xPosition, longitude: yPosition, title: clubName)
[...]
}
```

**My app crash when the line "self.mapSubViewController.mapLocationUpdate(...)" is executed.** When it's the "viewDidLoad" of the controller who tell the function "mapLocationUpdate", the app not crash.

I think it's because the map location cannot be change in the code after the map charged.

How i can do ?

Sorry for my english, I do my best :-) !

Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set a custom location on a map you should to something similar to this:

```
let pLat = 43.6109200
let pLong = 3.8772300
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pLat, longitude: pLong)

let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Comment: I understand and i do that on my function "centerMapOnLocation". When i tell mapLocationUpdate, the map go on my location, but i can't change this location after, because tha app crash. I search to change the location after the viewDidLoad, after the view are initialized

Comment: I change mu subjet to your code, but the problem is the same !

Comment: When you say "I can't change this location after" do you mean programatically or actually in the app "touching" the map? If it's the second option try enabling user interactions in the storyboard.

Comment: In the storyboard, i desactivate the user interaction because i juste want  map for a place (like a screenshot ^^). When i say "I can't change the location after", it's in the code, when i try to call "mapUpdateLocation" in my function "adMapView". If i comment this line : "self.mapSubViewController.mapLocationUpdate(...)", the app do not crash and the coordonate a the map are (43.6109200, 3.8772300) --> because initialization.

Comment: I don't know if I understood right, but you get the problem (can you write the console error you get?) when calling `mapLocationUpdate` from another `ViewController`, is it right? Probably it's because when you call it from an external `ViewController` the map view in `MapSubViewController` is already deallocated.

Comment: Yes ! Exactly ! my func `addMapView` is in an other controller. When the app crash (exactly, the app crash when `setRegion` is called by `addMapView`), the console error write `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Thx for your help !

Comment: How can i change the location or do something for my MapSubViewController do not deallocated ? (My english is terrible in this comment :-p)

Comment: Why don't you use a just single ViewController with the **Map** and the **User Logic** that you need? So you can refer to the map in any way you want.

Comment: Another option is to store the location in an external class (maybe a Singleton?) so you can save the location to it whenever you want and then when your `MapSubViewController` appears you load the current location from that Singleton.

Comment: In fact, myfunc addMapView is in a controller (FatherViewController) who manage many view. I can extends many controller to this controller. For example, i have a controller "SonViewController", in this controller i want place a map and a label. So `SonViewController : FatherViewController`, `self.addMapView(...), self.addLabelView(...)`. The FatherViewController do constraint and other UI actions automaticly

Comment: I understand the singleton, but I don't know how many time i will call addMapView, because, this function may be called from many different view, so a singleton could be resolve my problem, but it not really clean :/ But thank you, i understand why my app crash and you give me some solution. I can resolve alone now :) Thx a lot !

Comment: Do another answer with a small reponse of this discussion and i validate the answer ;) (If you want)

Comment: Well, in my opinion the Singleton is the best option for your scenario. You can store there the location whenever you have to, then in the ViewController with the map you can register (some kind of publisher/subscriber) with that singleton for updates on the viewDidLoad and then unregister when the view unload.

Comment: Yes i do that. I do a singleton and store my data. Work fine ! Thx ;)